# Linux -more than one root account

Tags: linux

First of all im not a trained linux personnel, i am required to audit . I need assistance to understand the below scenario.

etc/group 
root:x:0:root,syed

etc/passwd
syed:x:613:100::/home/syed:/bin/bash

My quest : Is syed has the root priviledge since UID not 0? 
            If yes, can i differentiate the activity done by syed and root or i can only see as a root activities ? cnt differentiate.

Thanks for the assistance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, Syed is not 'root'. He belongs to the groups with ids 0 and 100. A program like 'sudo' *might* be configured to allow users in group 0 to execute commands via it without a password but in the Unix kernel (ignoring capabilities) the extra abilities are all associated with *user id* 0, not *group id* 0.

Comment: So is that mean being in the GID 0 doesnt bring any privilege capabilities as root unless the UID 0?

Comment: some files, directories, device nodes, etc are readable and/or writable members of group 0, so any member of that group (including syed, above) would be able to read from or write to them.

Answer (score 0):

He has a different UID, but he is a member of the `root` group, so when group permissions come into play then the `syed` user would indeed have the same permissions as root.

Each user should have their own `.bash_history`, etc. so you should see separate lists of commands, etc. if that is what your audit tools depend on.

A better way if auditing is required is to set up `sudo` and require its use, since it logs use with the command, who ran it, the working directory, etc.

Comment: is it acceptable to have more user in GID =0 ?

Comment: yes it is both acceptable and normal.